# How to resolve an error: Property doesn not exists on type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm very new to TypeScript and I wanted to use the OpenCV js library inside a typescript file. I set `strict` to `false` to disable type checking, for now, just to test if this will work, but all of the OpenCV functions returns an error:

`Property Mat does not exist on type '(cv: any, ...args: any[]) => any'`

My code example:

```
import cv from "../OpenCV/opencv.js";

export class FaceRecognizer {
    
    private sourceMat: any;

    private grayMat: any

    private faceVector: any;

    private faceMat: any;

    private videoSource: HTMLVideoElement;
    
    private videoWidth: number;

    private videoHeight: number;


    constructor(videoSource: HTMLVideoElement) {
        this.sourceMat = new cv.Mat(this.videoHeight, this.videoWidth, cv.CV_8UC4);
        this.grayMat = new cv.Mat(this.videoHeight, this.videoWidth, cv.CV_8UC1);
        this.faceVector = new cv.RectVector();
        this.faceMat = new cv.Mat(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is how I defined types.

My folder structure:

```
src
  tsconfig.json
  @types
      OpenCV
          main.d.ts
          package.json
  OpenCV
    opencv.js
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "types",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "typings": "main.d.ts"
}
```

tsconfig.js

```
...
"declaration": false,
"typeRoots": [
   "node_modules/@types",
   "./src/@types"
]
```

main.d.ts

```
declare namespace cv {
    export function Mat(...args: any): any;
    export function rotatedRectPoints(...args: any): any;
    export function rotatedRectBoundingRect(...args: any): any;
    export function rotatedRectBoundingRect2f(...args: any): any;
    export function exceptionFromPtr(...args: any): any;
    export function minEnclosingCircle(...args: any): any;

      export class MatVector {
      push_back: any;
      resize: any;
      size: any;
      get: any;
      set: any;
    }
    export class RectVector {
      push_back: any;
      resize: any;
      size: any;
      get: any;
      set: any;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to install/add types for this library

Comment: I suppose you should use https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv4nodejs which is already supports TS

Comment: This library doesn't have types, I tried to use my own type definitions, but this still didn't work. opencv4nodejs is not what I want to use. Instead, I'm using compiled OpenCV's library with Emscripten

Comment: Then show how you defined types

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Don't you need something like `declare module 'package_name' {` at the beginning of `main.d.ts`?